# From which X value, Y starts to be different?

Tags: r, change-point

Here are data about the ventilation response (VE) to exercise (i.e., increase in oxygen consumption or VO2). In normal condition, ventilation increases linearly until a threshold where hyperventilation starts around 50 to 70% of peak VO2. However, with cardiac disease (here coronary artery disease or CAD), hyperventilation may start before.

I would like to know from which percentage the hyperventilation starts in CAD compared to the healthy individuals.
In other words, I would like to determine from which X value Y starts to be different between the 2 groups on this plot ?

My cardiac patients are fit and it might be possible that their ventilation are not different at any point.
What I can do at the moment is compare both groups at different point. For example, at each 10% from 0 to 100. But I would like to know if there is another way with R codes to see from which specific point they start to be different.

If so, what be the the mean+SD of this threshold in both groups, and what is the p-value ?

Thank you!

[image]

Here are the code I used to get the plot:

```
df %>% 
  filter(percent_absVO2 < 100) %>%
  ggscatter(x = "percent_absVO2", y = "VE", color = "group") +
  stat_cor(aes(color = group), label.x = 20, label.y = c(100,125)) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = 20, label.y = c(90,115), 
                        formula = y ~ poly(x, 2),
                        aes(color = group, label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour=group), method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)) +
  xlab("Percentage of VO2 (%)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("VE"," (L/min)")))
```

EDIT:
I already got the 2 breakpoints. I minimized `AIC`, `BIC`, `deviance`, or similar of a linear model using `optimize` where the two segments are defined as two functions:

```
df_CAD <- subset(df_sum, percent_absVO2 < 100 & group == 'CAD' & temps == '1')
df_healthy <- subset(df_sum, percent_absVO2 < 100 & group == 'Healthy')

f1 <- \(x, bp) ifelse(x < bp, bp - x, 0)
f2 <- \(x, bp) ifelse(x < bp, 0, x - bp)

main_CAD <- \(bp) BIC(lm(VE ~ f1(percent_absVO2, bp) + f2(percent_absVO2, bp), df_CAD))

(bp_CAD <- optimize(main_CAD, interval=range(df_CAD$percent_absVO2))$min)
```

Then, I did a piecewise regression:

```
a <- lm(VE ~ percent_absVO2, data=df_CAD, subset=percent_absVO2 <= bp_CAD)
b <- lm(VE ~ percent_absVO2, data=df_CAD, subset=percent_absVO2 > bp_CAD)
```

Then, I extracted the coefficients and created the two regression lines:

```
##extract coef
a_coef <- coef(a)
intercept_a_CAD <- a_coef[1]
slope_a_CAD <- a_coef[2]

b_coef <- coef(b)
intercept_b_CAD <- b_coef[1]
slope_b_CAD <- b_coef[2]

##create two regression lines
df_CAD$group <- 42
df_CAD[df_CAD$percent_absVO2 <= bp_CAD,]$group <- 1
df_CAD[df_CAD$percent_absVO2 >= bp_CAD,]$group <- 2
df_CAD$group <- as.factor(df_CAD$group)
```

And then I get the plot for CAD:

```
ggplot(df_CAD, aes(x = percent_absVO2, y = VE)) +
  geom_point(shape = 19, size = 0.7) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = bp_CAD),linetype="dashed") +
  annotate("text", x=bp_CAD-2, y=70, 
           label=paste0("VT1: ", round(bp_CAD, 0), "%"), angle=90, size = 12) +
  annotate("text", x=95, y=50, 
           label=paste0("slope: ", round(slope_b_CAD, 2)), 
           colour = "red", size = 12) +
  annotate("text", x=35, y=15, 
           label=paste0("slope: ", round(slope_a_CAD, 2)), 
           colour = "red", size = 12) +
  geom_smooth(data = df_CAD[df_CAD$group == 1,], method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, colour = "black", size = 0.5, se = F) +
  geom_smooth(data = df_CAD[df_CAD$group == 2,], method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, color = "black", size = 0.5, se = F) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour=group), method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), colour = "red") +
  stat_cor(color = "red", label.x = 20, label.y = c(100,125), size = 12) +
  stat_regline_equation(color = "red", label.x = 20, label.y = c(90,115), size = 12,
                        formula = y ~ poly(x, 2),
                        aes(color = group, label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),) +
  ylab(bquote("VE " (L*'·'*min^-1))) + 
  xlab(expression(paste("Percentage of V", O[2],", %"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 112.5), breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 25)) +
  labs(title="CAD") +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.title.y=element_text(size = 30),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(color="red", hjust = 0.5, size = 30),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=30),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=30))
```

I did the same for `healthy` and combined for plots (see attached figure)
[image]

And here are my data to work on:

```
structure(list(VE = c(22.75, 23.75, 26.75, 32.5, 39.5, 48.25, 
55.75, 24, 26.5, 29, 36.5, 44.75, 55.25, 63.75, 78, 19, 20.75, 
25, 29, 39.25, 51, 25, 25.5, 28.5, 34.25, 35.5, 40.25, 47, 52.5, 
59.5, 64.5, 83, 92.25, 18.25, 19.75, 20.75, 23.5, 26.25, 28, 
32.75, 37.25, 24.25, 26.75, 29.5, 31, 32, 39, 43.25, 46.25, 51.75, 
52.75, 64.5, 72.75, 15.75, 16.25, 20.25, 28, 34.75, 45.75, 64.75, 
18.25, 21.25, 22.25, 24.75, 29.5, 21.25, 20.75, 26, 30.75, 34, 
38.5, 46.75, 53.75, 70.5, 82.75, 98.25, 17.25, 22, 25.75, 29.75, 
33.75, 38.75, 44.5, 50.75, 56.25, 65, 71.75, 81, 99, 30, 29, 
29.75, 38.25, 40.75, 47.25, 52.75, 65.5, 22.75, 24.75, 28.75, 
34, 48, 53.75, 61.5, 73.75, 22, 21.75, 24.25, 28, 34.5, 40, 48.5, 
23.75, 23.75, 25.75, 29, 31.25, 33.5, 35.25, 38.5, 40.5, 50, 
62.5, 77.25, 19.5, 21.25, 24.25, 30.75, 38.5, 17, 17.25, 20.75, 
24.25, 28.5, 32.25, 38.75, 54.25, 21, 23.25, 28.25, 32.75, 37, 
46.5, 56.25, 65.5, 24.5, 25.75, 26.75, 29.5, 33.25, 37.75, 40, 
45.75, 50, 56.5, 23.75, 26.75, 29.75, 38.25, 43.75, 50.5, 58.5, 
69.75, 78.25, 92.75, 109, 123.25, 22.75, 23.75, 28.5, 32.75, 
39.75, 46.5, 56.5, 65.75, 76, 26.75, 26.5, 30.5, 31, 40.25, 44.75, 
52.5, 60, 65, 70.75, 78, 40.5, 43.75, 50.25, 63, 75, 82, 95.25, 
25.75, 27.5, 33, 37.75, 44, 53.5, 58.75, 69, 16.75, 19.75, 24.75, 
31.25, 38, 49.75, 63.25, 22.25, 24.25, 26.75, 30.25, 35.5, 40.5, 
46, 53.5, 60.75, 68.5, 22, 22.25, 25.75, 28.75, 35.5, 41.25, 
50.25, 20.5, 20.5, 24.75, 29.25, 37.5, 37.75, 43.5, 47, 51.5, 
56.25, 63, 76.5, 14.25, 17.75, 18.75, 22.5, 25.5, 28, 33.5, 37.5, 
42.75, 43.5, 57.25, 72, 93, 23.25, 25, 27, 27.25, 28, 33.25, 
35.75, 37.75, 42.75, 46.25, 47.5, 55.25, 58, 64.75, 67.25, 72.5, 
77, 83.5, 20.25, 20.5, 23.5, 25, 27.75, 31.5, 35.5, 40, 46.75, 
23.5, 26, 26.5, 31, 36.25, 42, 48.5, 56, 67.25, 78.5, 20.25, 
21.5, 24, 27, 32, 40, 47.75, 23.25, 21.5, 29.75, 33, 36, 42.75, 
49, 54.5, 61.25, 67.25, 74.75, 89.25, 108, 116.5, 29, 32.75, 
35.25, 40.5, 45, 48.75, 58.5, 63.75, 74.75, 84.5, 89.25, 105, 
112.75, 21, 24.75, 23.5, 26.75, 29.5, 37.75, 45, 52.25, 60.25, 
73.25, 23.25, 25.75, 30.25, 39.5, 43.25, 57.25, 67, 20.25, 22.25, 
25.25, 28.5, 32.5, 42.5, 58, 20.75, 24.5, 27.25, 32.5, 36.25, 
42.25, 48, 54, 62, 73.75, 22.25, 25, 29.5, 32.75, 39.5, 46.5, 
56.25, 66.5, 19.5, 20.75, 23, 29.75, 33.5, 40, 51, 55.25, 66.25, 
78.75, 93.25, 22.75, 23.25, 26.5, 31.5, 34.25, 43, 46.75, 51.75, 
57.5, 65, 83.5, 100.75, 17, 20.25, 23, 25.25, 32.5, 38.5, 43, 
51.75, 55.5, 67, 78.25, 98.75, 25, 26, 32.5, 38, 48, 51.75, 70.5, 
18.25, 18.5, 20.5, 22.25, 25.25, 29.25, 31.75, 35.75, 40.75, 
42.25, 48, 53.5, 60.25, 67.75, 77.25, 24.5, 23.5, 26.25, 29.25, 
32.75, 36, 38, 41.5, 19.25, 20.25, 23.5, 29.25, 32, 36, 41.25, 
30.5, 30.75, 33, 37, 42.25, 48.25, 53.5, 63, 76.25, 18.75, 20.5, 
26.5, 30.25, 35.75, 38, 42, 48, 53.5, 63, 30, 34.25, 36.75, 41.75, 
43.25, 47.5, 55.25, 57.25, 65.25, 74.25, 21, 21, 23.25, 28.5, 
35.25, 46.75, 21, 23, 25.5, 32, 36.75, 44, 51, 60, 69.25, 85, 
21, 21.75, 25.75, 29.25, 33.25, 38.5, 47.75, 54.5, 64.5, 20.25, 
20.25, 24, 27.25, 30.75, 34.25, 38.75, 44.5, 51.5, 54.5, 22.75, 
23.25, 28.5, 29.5, 36.25, 40.5, 49.5, 53.5, 68, 81.75, 98.25, 
20.5, 22.5, 24.5, 25.5, 28.25, 32.25, 45.75, 43.75, 47.5, 54.75, 
60, 68.75, 81.75, 90.25, 23.25, 24, 29.5, 32.25, 34.75, 40.75, 
45.75, 51.75, 56, 63.5, 68.5, 77.25, 85.5, 97, 108.5, 22, 25.75, 
26, 34.75, 37, 45.75, 52, 63, 69, 89.5, 105.75, 16.75, 16.25, 
21.25, 24, 26.25, 32.75, 36, 40.75, 44.5, 50), percent_absVO2 = c(49.3406776831915, 
54.7320981472208, 63.5119345685195, 71.791019863128, 80.0534134535136, 
89.8514438324153, 100, 41.3669064748201, 46.8251485767907, 53.4876446668752, 
61.588989677823, 71.9111667187989, 84.2352205192368, 90.7725993118549, 
100, 48.8708399366086, 56.8145800316957, 68.3637083993661, 78.1101426307448, 
89.540412044374, 100, 36.1571516267649, 38.7047268262738, 44.2500511561285, 
50.9105790873747, 53.3967669326785, 60.3028442807448, 68.7129118068345, 
73.2862696951095, 80.2128094945774, 83.5072641702476, 95.9382033967669, 
100, 49.2621076699231, 54.9573893161505, 61.8166701309499, 73.0617335273332, 
78.4452296819788, 82.8725836624402, 92.6418623986697, 100, 45.3787693062025, 
50.4658004412846, 54.7560676636431, 58.7031135082128, 61.1792105908311, 
69.9313557244423, 75.6190242706546, 78.1686687913704, 83.1944103947046, 
87.0801667075264, 95.3787693062025, 100, 40.3316999623068, 44.0633245382586, 
57.9532604598568, 74.0294006784772, 82.9061439879382, 94.9114210327931, 
100, 61.4367938605841, 74.0353869111064, 78.7465359198465, 86.1863142187167, 
100, 34.7511100724468, 35.7910726805328, 44.905351717691, 51.2970320168264, 
57.0109838747371, 62.8768403832671, 70.4019630754849, 78.3126898808133, 
87.0881046973592, 95.653189997663, 100, 24.7776879547292, 34.569523039612, 
39.6119644300728, 43.4923201293452, 52.021018593371, 59.0743734842361, 
64.3997574777688, 68.57316087308, 76.1519805982215, 80.7599029911075, 
86.6006467259499, 93.4822150363783, 100, 54.0860573715811, 53.6024016010674, 
57.6717811874583, 71.7811874583056, 74.6497665110073, 83.7224816544363, 
89.2761841227485, 100, 53.017170891251, 57.988552739166, 67.8495502861815, 
74.1782502044154, 82.8618152085037, 89.1414554374489, 94.5543744889616, 
100, 55.995670995671, 57.5324675324675, 64.2424242424242, 70.7142857142857, 
85.1082251082251, 92.5324675324675, 100, 50.0610649731314, 50.4885197850513, 
53.505129457743, 59.4406448461163, 62.6770884220811, 67.9164631167562, 
70.2491450903761, 76.9418661455789, 79.6653639472399, 87.9579872984856, 
95.5422569614069, 100, 71.3170486023672, 72.979098463863, 83.2787710904054, 
93.0747922437673, 100, 41.6474565852159, 42.8000614722606, 49.5466420777624, 
58.9057937605656, 66.0365759950822, 76.932534193945, 84.4167819271554, 
100, 47.9377549478773, 50.8233872186131, 58.7853150022662, 63.4083698443874, 
70.6602205771265, 85.3452183109231, 92.5366369542227, 100, 45.2115812917595, 
47.6455615653834, 54.2316258351893, 58.7814190264079, 67.1810372255807, 
73.4966592427617, 78.1419026407891, 85.0302258988228, 92.9366846961502, 
100, 32.9242861726019, 39.4610202117421, 42.5409047160731, 50.5373756817453, 
55.2614693615656, 61.1806223933269, 68.599615014437, 75.4491498235483, 
80.9512351620148, 88.3942893808149, 94.7786333012512, 100, 41.8658220558595, 
43.8093866973798, 53.7575583069392, 60.7255974661676, 70.7745465015837, 
78.9375179959689, 83.3141376331702, 91.693060754391, 100, 47.4348291870015, 
47.1848589453637, 57.0884418521605, 57.4336388525176, 68.0633257945483, 
72.5746934888704, 75.5624330436853, 81.4545887394358, 89.7155100583264, 
94.0602309248899, 100, 54.7165775401069, 60.6310160427808, 66.1818181818182, 
77.668449197861, 84.5347593582888, 92.5561497326203, 100, 46.2385583524027, 
50.0143020594966, 57.9948512585812, 65.6464530892448, 73.5697940503432, 
81.9221967963387, 89.2448512585812, 100, 36.4009186351706, 43.1430446194226, 
56.1515748031496, 66.2729658792651, 73.3759842519685, 90.0754593175853, 
100, 45.4926928085661, 49.8914773549414, 55.9976848502387, 65.8515410215598, 
73.8532773838808, 81.5077412820142, 90.059325712632, 94.2989437129214, 
95.8906091737809, 100, 60.2059496567506, 62.0366132723112, 66.7048054919909, 
71.7162471395881, 79.6109839816934, 91.1899313501144, 100, 34.3442794394478, 
32.901066722443, 45.5657812173186, 50.6379418531688, 59.5377536080318, 
63.4176950428781, 68.7931395105626, 75.7686676427525, 79.8682284040996, 
89.7720142229659, 91.7799623509726, 100, 21.0665159223667, 27.5485208215564, 
33.4087054833239, 39.871867345016, 45.6849444130394, 50.9233088373846, 
60.2788769549651, 65.7056717542868, 72.5174298096853, 76.2106651592237, 
87.752025626531, 93.6216318070473, 100, 37.771525042206, 39.2346651660101, 
45.2898142937535, 49.2628024760833, 47.1018570624648, 57.5464265616207, 
61.7895329206528, 64.0180078784468, 69.7580191333708, 71.8851997749015, 
74.091164884637, 84.6595385481148, 87.1581316826111, 93.2020258863253, 
94.946539110861, 94.7101857062465, 99.527293190771, 100, 49.8566368696239, 
50.6156181480857, 57.834373418789, 62.742452352842, 67.2626075223478, 
75.6451340866925, 83.3867431270029, 91.2464159217406, 100, 42.8522843215055, 
45.2896496995805, 51.5020972678835, 58.7801836526471, 67.0672259381023, 
74.06189774402, 81.8501303707063, 88.4706949325473, 95.5787325700034, 
100, 56.6379783922359, 61.1609595312214, 74.4735396447537, 79.6374290422999, 
88.0424830617103, 97.4546786302875, 100, 30.6553512494106, 34.1254125412541, 
43.5549269212636, 47.4681753889675, 49.7689768976898, 56.6996699669967, 
61.4710042432815, 67.3550212164074, 72.8429985855728, 81.1881188118812, 
85.2616690240453, 94.4365865157944, 100, 99.6888260254597, 36.1955085865258, 
40.5107881990313, 45.1166886833994, 51.7305151915456, 56.5565830030823, 
62.9942756494936, 69.8546895640687, 73.8000880669309, 79.5948921180097, 
87.4680757375606, 90.5416116248349, 96.6886833993835, 100, 38.3808891838089, 
50.6171201061712, 48.8122096881221, 55.7664233576642, 60.836098208361, 
70.0597213005972, 78.0358327803583, 85.1891174518912, 92.7272727272727, 
100, 48.2647058823529, 52.8235294117647, 62.8235294117647, 75.5147058823529, 
79.75, 91.25, 100, 42.3174603174603, 49.2539682539683, 57.0634920634921, 
67.0952380952381, 76.1746031746032, 88.968253968254, 100, 35.5025474756832, 
40.748031496063, 47.2093561834183, 54.3191292264937, 60.6067623899954, 
70.1366373320982, 76.4937471051413, 84.0435386753127, 92.8902269569245, 
100, 43.5580204778157, 49.2605233219568, 57.2952218430034, 63.1114903299204, 
75.3839590443686, 84.1012514220705, 91.6097838452787, 100, 32.9112505602869, 
37.012550425818, 40.02689376961, 51.1653966831017, 56.2079784849843, 
65.5535634244733, 75.5939040788884, 77.1066786194532, 85.8695652173913, 
92.974002689377, 100, 36.4077122561732, 36.2611342879693, 40.8952531288759, 
47.6942158078701, 53.6926372759048, 62.149058518435, 68.034727703236, 
72.7928740556996, 81.5311760063141, 90.0326981621378, 97.3954222573007, 
100, 31.8239282841053, 37.6278588667969, 42.029651764165, 47.7991035513159, 
55.1660728651879, 62.3031835421216, 66.5555683254798, 74.0374669578209, 
80.6114239742558, 86.5762556028043, 92.10435582117, 100, 58.7913162526892, 
60.4341873655388, 74.2616858986896, 81.517699980442, 91.5313905730491, 
97.2227654997066, 100, 35.638106650689, 34.9310964649491, 39.3529059316956, 
43.3912522468544, 48.3523067705213, 53.301378070701, 57.9149191132415, 
62.2528460155782, 67.5733972438586, 71.168364289994, 76.3211503894547, 
83.0557219892151, 88.3403235470341, 93.09766327142, 100, 61.3662024840045, 
57.9412871659767, 65.6567557395559, 74.764772299586, 81.5769665035754, 
89.0477982687241, 96.8573579224689, 100, 59.9159074982481, 61.4108853071712, 
66.9236159775754, 72.2027563653352, 83.2982947909367, 89.6052324223312, 
100, 50.5689576695494, 50.1744803519951, 54.0282203004096, 60.6433014717038, 
66.8790775299651, 77.0444545592474, 83.8416021847975, 91.9435593991807, 
100, 32.6292246520875, 36.6674950298211, 48.3474155069582, 54.6719681908549, 
64.4632206759443, 66.5134194831014, 74.1053677932405, 80.5914512922465, 
90.8548707753479, 100, 56.6227326112489, 59.7416155552656, 63.4346861542477, 
68.2369829048675, 71.642959676367, 78.3896646222106, 86.7545347775023, 
88.9338379224847, 95.3803993214146, 100, 69.448333800056, 70.1484178101372, 
76.2531503780453, 85.4942593111173, 91.0109213105573, 100, 35.8301264431006, 
40.4205607476636, 45.7943925233645, 57.39417262232, 61.9021440351842, 
71.9488730071468, 80.7998900494777, 88.8125343595382, 98.3644859813084, 
100, 44.0334961618981, 46.301465457083, 51.8143754361479, 57.728541521284, 
64.8639218422889, 74.2323796231682, 87.0551290997906, 91.9574319609211, 
100, 47.6308345120226, 46.8175388967468, 57.9738330975955, 64.7454031117397, 
70.4384724186704, 76.7503536067892, 86.8281471004243, 91.7432814710042, 
98.3203677510608, 100, 34.2491610738255, 37.2692953020134, 44.1275167785235, 
47.5251677852349, 58.7353187919463, 63.8527684563758, 71.8645134228188, 
79.5511744966443, 87.5419463087248, 93.8548657718121, 100, 28.7538802660754, 
31.1130820399113, 36.2749445676275, 39.2727272727273, 44.5055432372505, 
51.5210643015521, 60.9578713968958, 63.2727272727273, 70.6430155210643, 
75.6186252771619, 81.7472283813747, 88.5853658536585, 95.4323725055432, 
100, 26.7177479803448, 29.907553926876, 39.7851253435496, 43.8410926959274, 
46.0064962105439, 54.0934454901308, 57.9495294411593, 63.2464395769135, 
68.2351961355876, 74.6148080286499, 79.8201049387857, 84.817189972516, 
91.5299408678271, 96.3604564004331, 100, 39.8445286027506, 45.2262308152282, 
47.3390472393861, 62.1387283236994, 60.962726729121, 71.2178592784533, 
74.9750847119793, 80.875024915288, 86.3065577038071, 93.3824995016943, 
100, 49.3675889328063, 47.9644268774704, 56.699604743083, 67.7667984189723, 
73.1818181818182, 85.3952569169961, 91.5612648221344, 96.0671936758894, 
99.1106719367589, 100), group = c("CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -561L))
```

Comment: I am not sure. I am asking help about the code needed to be able to determine the threshold from where starts the difference. But I will ask stats.stackexchange if nobody can help me here. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'd also suggest you describe the models you're currently using. It seems like your data has 10 columns, but you're only using 3 of them? Do you want to use the others? (If not, you could significantly shorten your data extract by only sharing the relevant columns.)

Comment: If you know the model/algorithm/statistical test you want to use and you need help programming it, that seems like a programming question. You don't seem to know what model, algorithm, or statistical test to use, which makes it a statistical problem.

Comment: If all you want to do is the programmatic version of graphically identifying the x values starting around 70 and going through around 95 where there's an tiny bit of white space between the confidence intervals of your line, then that seems like a programming question. But it also seems rather dubious statistically.

Comment: I have updated the question and give the full data only on the relevant columns.

Comment: I thought that it was only a 1-way ANOVA (or possibly t-test) comparison of the mean+SD of Y value between each group according their `geom_smooth`, but at each X point from `0` to `100` and determine from which one it starts to be different (or from which one P<0.05). Thank you !

Comment: That sounds like poor statistics to me. Which is why I would suggest asking at stats.stackexchange so they can point you in a better direction methodologically.

Comment: Your model seems to be clearly incorrect as the confidence intervals are uniform while the variability of the data increases with $x$-axis data.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have edited the question and put the code I have used to get the regression lines in both groups.

Comment: I think you need to spell out more about the data and the question. you want to answer. Avoid the word "significant" as that often leads to fuzzy thinking. What exactly do you want to know? Why do you think there is a sharp cutoff for where the curves diverge? Why a polynomial model? Do the fit parameters from that model have a biological meaning?

Comment: Thank you @HarveyMotulsky. I have updated the question and added some rational about my question. I hope it helps to get the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is that ventilation (Y) increases linearly with oxygen consumption (X) until a threshold is reached, after which the relation is still linear but the slope is steeper. Your question is whether this threshold changes with coronary artery disease. (Right?)

I don't know how well established this model is, and don't really see that kind of segmented linear regression in your graph. I suspect some sort of curve will better describe the data. But let's go with the model you suggested.

Your model can be fit to determine both slopes and the intercept,  but you will care most about the threshold (breakpoint). All parameters are fit with confidence intervals. The term to search for is "segmented" (sometimes "segmental" or "piecewise") linear regression.

[An R package does that analysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/segmented.pdf).

[A simpler explanation.](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/8/8.8)

[Another explanation](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_segmental_linear_regression.htm) (written by me)

As @Tim pointed out in the comments, the scatter gets larger as Y gets larger. So weighting the regression is appropriate. Learn about weighting [here](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_segmental_linear_regression.htm) and [here](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_practical_details_of_weighting.htm).

As @whuber pointed out in comments, the model would have to be extended. It would need to fit the control threshold or breakpoint and also the difference in breakpoint with coronary artery disease. Then look at whether the 95% confidence interval for that difference in breakpoint includes zero or not.

Comment: This doesn't sound right, because piecewise linear regression does not in itself solve a changepoint problem like this one appears to be.  How is this piecewise regression to be carried out with *two different datasets* and--most importantly--how is the breakpoint to be determined?

Comment: @whuber As you point out, the model would have to be extended. It would need to fit the control breakpoint and also the difference in breakpoint with coronary artery disease. Then look at whether the 95% confidence interval for that difference in breakpoint includes zero or not.

Comment: Thank you for all of these suggestions and I have clarified the question. I already got the 2breakpoints (one in each group) as you can see now in the post. The breakpoint is defined as follow: when the the slope start to be different within each group. We can see that it is 70 and 77% in the CAD an healthy groups, respectively. What I would like to know is "From which %VO2, VE starts to be different between CAD and healthy individuals ?", using the polynomial regression. I hope it is clearer. And thank you all!